# How get original price from rounded value in php?

Tags: php, math, formatting

I have a code like this `$new_amount = round(($old_amount/53),2);`

amount may be 1,2, ...,10000;

How get exact `$old_amount` from `$new_amount;` Now i tried to use

```
$old_amount = ceil($new_amount);` AND `$old_amount = floor($new_amount);
```

but not working properly; please help me;

Comment: Not possible. You need to store the copy of the original amount somehow.

Comment: Can you not just read the original amount from `$old_amount;`?

Comment: You can read it from `$old_amount`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think he meant retrieve the old amount at some other time other place

Comment: ya. $old_number is intiger;

Comment: but i get $old_amount either from ciel() or floor(); but the problem is some times ciel() gives correct answer some times floor gives correct answer

Answer (score 3):

You can't, once you round a value you get rid of the extra precision.  This precision is lost.  However, the old value is still stored in the `$old_amount` variable.

Comment: What has the type got to do with it?

Comment: but i get $old_amount either from ciel() or floor(); but the problem is some times ciel() gives correct answer some times floor gives correct answer

Comment: You will need to explain more in your question since even if it is an integer, the fact you are dividing then rounding means you will lose precision, precision that there is no way to get back.  This is why reading the original value is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact amount, don't change the $old_amount while creating $new_amount. So you can use $old_amount later.

There is no way to back. Both Ceil() and floor() functions can't give you what you want.

Comment: but i get $old_amount either from ciel() or floor(); but the problem is some times ciel() gives correct answer some times floor gives correct answer

Comment: What do you want to get? Rounded value or the precision of the value? Ceil() and floor() remove the precision and give you integer. For example $x is 4 in ´$x=3.2; $x=ceil($x)´, or $x is 3 in ´$x=3.2; $x=floor($x)´ Have a lookt at those pages: http://php.net/floor , http://tr2.php.net/ceil , http://tr2.php.net/round